# Why isn't the javascript code not working for the svg object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm new to using svg inside html documents. Starting off with basics, I'm loading up a svg file through an object tag and then manipulating a part of the svg object through javascript.
This is the code:

```html
<html>
  <head>  </head>
  <body>        
    <object id="svg-object" data="ais3_cfg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"> </object>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          document.getElementsByClassName("node");
          var a = document.getElementById("node1");
          a.setAttribute("fill","red");
        });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The selected box should have red coloured font.
[image]

Comment: unfortunatelly it's not possible, you can't style object svg with external css styles

Comment: @svyatis.lviv i've followed videos such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyBmo_VffWI&ab_channel=LevelUpTuts, where it shows that it is possible

Comment: That's a tutorial on **inline** SVG styling, not styling SVG included via an object tag, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for that, i thought it should still work. i've tried with javascript now but am still getting an error (edited my question accordingly).

Comment: You need to get the object element's document and use that, that's a different document.

Comment: @hi_it'sme
Why you don't use fill: red; ? in your css code

Comment: "node1" refers to a `<g>` tag - which just defines a group.  Perhaps, if this were to work at all, you should be targeting the `<path>` tag within it?

Comment: @sm10 i tried initially, but it only works if you have inline svg code in the html document, which i can't have

Answer (score 0):

Object element contents are in their own separate document.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      let doc = document.getElementById("svg-object").contentDocument;
      var a = doc.getElementById("node1");
      a.setAttribute("fill","red");
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Presumably because node1's colours are being overridden by its children as a commenter on the question explained.

Comment: The `<path>` tag doesnt have any id or class that i can use, and if I physically create one for it, it destroys the overall objective since I shouldn't be needing to edit the svg file. Do you have any other idea that could possibly work?

Comment: you could iterate through the group's children via element.children till you found the right one. You are swimming with one hand tied behind your back if you refuse to edit the SVG document though.